# onepage checkout doesn't works fine when Full Page Cache enable

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, full-page-cache

When I checkout in Magento 2 from one-page checkout first time order placed successfully but the second time the order goes failure. but when I disable Full Page Cache it working fine.

Without disabling entire FPC, please tell me if there is any way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Please let me know if you are using caching module for that ? 
If yes, then you can ignore the checkout page from being caching using module admin setting.

Comment: no i am not using any module for caching

Comment: make sure your checkout block has cacheable="false". <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Onepage" name="checkout.root" template="onepage.phtml" cacheable="false">